# How to realloc a free()'d struct again correctly?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, pointers, malloc

I'd like to create a program, which monitors some processes. To do that, I created a struct, which contains the processes to monitor, another struct, which contains, which processes are still running, and a thread, which does the work. In the thread, (the struct, which contains the running processes) `ProcArrayDisplay`, will be free()'d, to empty the struct, and then malloc()'d, and filled again. I am not sure, if this is the best way. And here is my problem. If 2 or more processes are running, I always get `Access vioalation`.

I think this is because, the Counter of the struct is a global variable, and when the Thread modifies it, something goes wrong. I tried to use, `Critical sections` and `InterLockedIncrement/InterLockedDecrement` but I still get `Access violation`.

So what am I doing wrong, and how should I do it right?

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

struct ProcToQuery
{
   wchar_t * ProcessName;
   wchar_t * DisplayName;
};
struct ProcToQuery **ProcArrayQuery = NULL;
int ProcArrayCountQuery = 0;

struct ProcToDisplay
{
   wchar_t * ProcessName;
   wchar_t * DisplayName;
};
struct ProcToDisplay **ProcArrayDisplay = NULL;
volatile long ProcArrayCountDisplay = 0;

typedef struct
{
   BOOL bKill;
}PARAMS, *PPARAMS;

void AddItemsToQueryArray( wchar_t * ProcessName, wchar_t * DisplayName );
void AddItemsToDisplayArray( wchar_t * ProcessName, wchar_t * DisplayName );
void FreeStruct();
void FreeStructDisplay();
BOOL IsProcessRunning( wchar_t * ProcessName, wchar_t * DisplayName );
unsigned __stdcall Thread( void *ArgList );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
AddItemsToQueryArray( L"notepad.exe", L"Notepad" );
AddItemsToQueryArray( L"calc.exe", L"Calculator" );

PARAMS params;
params.bKill = FALSE;
unsigned int ThreadId;

for ( int i = 0; i < ProcArrayCountQuery; i++ )
{
    if ( !IsProcessRunning( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->ProcessName, ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->DisplayName ) )
    {
        // IsProcessRunning failed
        return 1;
    }
}

if ( ProcArrayCountDisplay == 0 )
{
    printf( "\nNone of the processes are running" );
    FreeStruct();
    return 0;
}

HANDLE hThread = ( HANDLE )_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, Thread, &params, 0, &ThreadId );

// do some work
Sleep(20000);

params.bKill = TRUE;
DWORD dwExitCode;
DWORD dwRet = WaitForSingleObject( hThread, 2000 );
if ( dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
{
    // the thread has terminated 
    GetExitCodeThread( hThread, &dwExitCode );
    printf( "\nThread finished ExitCode = %d", dwExitCode );
}
else if ( dwRet == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
{
    // thread still active
    GetExitCodeThread( hThread, &dwExitCode );
    printf( "\nThread still active ExitCode = %d", dwExitCode );

}
else if ( dwRet == WAIT_FAILED )
{
    printf( "\nWaitForSingleObject failed = %d", GetLastError() );
}

CloseHandle( hThread );

_getch();

return 0;
}

void AddItemsToQueryArray( wchar_t * ProcessName, wchar_t * DisplayName )
{
struct ProcToQuery **tmp = ( struct ProcToQuery ** )realloc( ProcArrayQuery, ( ProcArrayCountQuery + 1 ) * sizeof( struct ProcToQuery * ) );
if ( tmp == NULL )
{
    return;
}
ProcArrayQuery = tmp;

ProcArrayQuery[ ProcArrayCountQuery ] = ( struct ProcToQuery * )malloc( sizeof **ProcArrayQuery );
if ( ProcArrayQuery[ ProcArrayCountQuery ] == NULL )
{
    return;
}

ProcArrayQuery[ ProcArrayCountQuery ]->ProcessName = _wcsdup( ProcessName );
ProcArrayQuery[ ProcArrayCountQuery ]->DisplayName = _wcsdup( DisplayName );

ProcArrayCountQuery++;

}//AddItemsToQueryArray

void AddItemsToDisplayArray( wchar_t * ProcessName, wchar_t * DisplayName )
{
struct ProcToDisplay **tmp = ( struct ProcToDisplay ** )realloc( ProcArrayDisplay, ( ProcArrayCountDisplay + 1 ) * sizeof( struct ProcToDisplay * ) );
if ( tmp == NULL )
{
    return;
}
ProcArrayDisplay = tmp;

ProcArrayDisplay[ ProcArrayCountDisplay ] = ( struct ProcToDisplay * )malloc( sizeof **ProcArrayDisplay );
if ( ProcArrayDisplay[ ProcArrayCountDisplay ] == NULL )
{
    return;
}

ProcArrayDisplay[ ProcArrayCountDisplay ]->ProcessName = _wcsdup( ProcessName );
ProcArrayDisplay[ ProcArrayCountDisplay ]->DisplayName = _wcsdup( DisplayName );

ProcArrayCountDisplay++;

}//AddItemsToDisplayArray

void FreeStruct()
{
for ( int i = 0; i < ProcArrayCountQuery; i++ )
{
    if ( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->DisplayName ) free( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->DisplayName );
    if ( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->ProcessName ) free( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->ProcessName );
    if ( ProcArrayQuery[ i ] ) free( ProcArrayQuery[ i ] );
}
free( ProcArrayQuery );

FreeStructDisplay();
free( ProcArrayDisplay );
}//FreeStruct

void FreeStructDisplay()
{
for ( int i = 0; i < ProcArrayCountDisplay; i++ )
{
    if ( ProcArrayDisplay[ i ]->ProcessName ) free( ProcArrayDisplay[ i ]->ProcessName );
    if ( ProcArrayDisplay[ i ]->DisplayName ) free( ProcArrayDisplay[ i ]->DisplayName );
    if ( ProcArrayDisplay[ i ] ) free( ProcArrayDisplay[ i ] );
    ProcArrayCountDisplay--;
}
}

BOOL IsProcessRunning( wchar_t * ProcessName, wchar_t * DisplayName )
{
PROCESSENTRY32 process;

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
if ( snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    return FALSE;
}

ZeroMemory( &process, sizeof( process ) );
process.dwSize = sizeof( process );

if ( Process32First( snapshot, &process ) )
{
    do
    {
        if ( ( _wcsicmp( process.szExeFile, ProcessName ) == 0 ) )
        {
            printf("\n%ls is running", ProcessName );
            AddItemsToDisplayArray( ProcessName, DisplayName );
        }
    } while ( Process32Next( snapshot, &process ) == TRUE );

}
else
{
    // Process32First failed
    CloseHandle( snapshot );
    return FALSE;
}

CloseHandle( snapshot );

return TRUE;
}

unsigned __stdcall Thread( void *ArgList )
{

PPARAMS pparams;

pparams = ( PPARAMS )ArgList;
while ( !pparams->bKill )
{
    // Request ownership of the critical section.
//      EnterCriticalSection( &CriticalSection );

    FreeStructDisplay();
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------");
    for ( int i = 0; i < ProcArrayCountQuery; i++ )
    {
        if ( !IsProcessRunning( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->ProcessName, ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->DisplayName ) )
        {
            // IsProcessRunning failed
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if ( ProcArrayCountDisplay == 0 )
    {
        // no package to display
        break;
    }

    // Release ownership of the critical section.
//  LeaveCriticalSection( &CriticalSection );

    Sleep( 1000 );
}

_endthread();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `realloc a free()'d struct`... wait, are you expecting to get back the `free()`d data?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, I don't want to get back the free()'d data. I free struct, so it will be empty, and then fill it with malloc again. Sorry, if I can'T explain better, what I want. My english is not the best.

Comment: Can't you just "zero" (`memset`) your structure instead ? You should free it only when you know you do not need it anymore.
Note that `free` does not empty your struct: it marks the allocated space as available for another allocation.
Also Please narrow the relevant code parts.

Comment: @Coconop: That's already the relevant code parts. This is part of a bigger program, but that is the relevant part. I don't know if memset-ing is ok or not. That's what I am asking, how should i do it correctly?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find out which line of code is crashing?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes I have. I just found what was wrong. In the function `FreeStructDisplay` I decrement the variable `ProcArrayCountDisplay` which is the count of the array, and that`s obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is accessible by different thread and re-used multiple times I would suggest to:

- allocate it once
- protect it with a `mutex`: surround manipulations of this struct with `lock`/`unlock`
- use `memset` to empty your structure, i.e. set all fields to 0
- free it once you know it won't be used anymore

From what I understood, You want to "empty" your structure so `memset` seems a good solution (although you could just overwrite fields when needed): it shall fix the access violation issue since your structure will still exist (don't forget to check the fields values before using it though).
As said in comment, `free` does NOT "empty" your structure: it just flags the memory you reserved via `malloc` as available again. The content will remain unchanged until something else writes into it.

**[EDIT]**
My bad, I missed the fact that you were using `wcsdup` which allocate a new string that shall bee `free`.
It could be avoided if you know a priori the maximal size of the strings you are manipulating:

```
struct ProcToQuery
{
   wchar_t ProcessName[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
   wchar_t DisplayName[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
};
```

Then you could use `wcscpy` instead of `wcsdup` and you would not need new allocation.
The same goes for `ProcArrayQuery`:

```
struct ProcToQuery * ProcArrayQuery[MAX_QUERY];
```

Comment: If I always use memset, then the memory still stays allocated, right? This struct can grow, and can shrink, depending on how many processes are still running, from the processes i want to monitor. If I use memset, then just the data will get NULLd out, and the Counter must be set back to 0. After that i have to add, the elements again, which are still running, so the Counter wont hold the Count of the allocated elements, and therefore they can't be freed correctly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: "The memory stays allocated": right. If he struct needs to grow/shrink then memset isnt enough: you need to realloc. The memory allocated via malloc will be freed correctly. If the struct contains nested allocated elements, they shall be freed before the memset if they are not referenced elsewhere to avoid memory leak

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand it fully. If I just memset the struct, and add it again, then the debugger shows, that there is a lot of memory which hasn't been free()d. The function `AddItemsToDisplayArray` adds an item to the array, and the function `FreeStructDisplay` frees it. I call these two functions in a loop. And on program exit, I call `FreeStruct()`, which calls `FreeStructDisplay()` and then `free( ProcArrayDisplay );`

Comment: But in this case, the array is a fix sized array. Unfortunately I need a dynamically growing array(that's why I use my array the way I do). I don't know how many processes will there be. It could be 1, but it could be 10, or more too.

Comment: Then keep the dynamic allocation for the array but go for static allocation of the names it contains: it will save you some malloc

Comment: Sorry, but the names must be dynamic allocations as well

Comment: Mmmh then I am sorry but I don't see an other alternative